# $1 credit card verification for Braintree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

guys.
I'm using [Braintree](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby) for site payments.
Trying to provide $1 credit card verification.
I have found in guide the piece of code.

```
result = Braintree::Customer.create(
  :first_name => "Fred",
  :last_name => "Jones",
  :credit_card => {
    :payment_method_nonce => nonce_from_the_client,
    :options => {
      :verify_card => true
    }
  }
)
```

Is this $1 dollar verification with `verify_card` parameter?

Thanks a lot.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You can enable card verification for all transactions in your control panel, or enable it on a specific operation, like you're doing here, by passing the "verify_card" option. With either method [the process for verifying a card is the same](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/card-verification#card-verification) and includes $1 verifications where needed:

> The gateway will first attempt a $0 verification, regardless of bank or processor. In the event that a bank doesn't accept a $0 verification, they'll normally respond with a message prompting Braintree to attempt a $1 verification instead, which Braintree will do automatically upon receiving the message. Even if the bank does not send this message, Braintree gives you the option to retry all failed $0 verifications, which you can enable in the control panel.

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in the Braintree integration with my project and I was checking document cursory to complete my all requirements, mostly all features are there, only I did not find the types of allowed business account type for the merchant Id detail like I want to use PayPal account as a bank account so is it allowed or not?

Comment: @BunkerBoy, the details of merchant accounts aren't relevant to this question. To get the best answer, I recommend opening a new question or [contacting Braintree support directly](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).